# В одиночестве и в отчаянии" или "в одиночестве и отчаянии"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как будет правильно, скажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Повтор предлога регулируется **правилом Розенталя.**

§207. Предлоги при однородных членах [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm#%D0%B7_02)

Предлог, стоящий перед первым однородным членом, может опускаться перед остальными однородными членами, но может и повторяться перед каждым из них. Ср.: Хозяин, из почтения и радости, ничего не ел... (Пушкин). – Феничка вся покраснела от смущения и от радости (Тургенев).

Интересно отметить, что при использовании союза И пропуск предлога характерен при соединении достаточно **близких понятий**, что видно из примеров.

В первом предложении однородные члены  **сходны по смыслу**, поэтому предлог опущен. Во втором же предложении  семантика дополнений **различается** в большей степени, соответственно, предлог повторяется.

В нашем случае мы имеем скорее близкую семантику, поэтому предлог лучше опустить: ***в одиночестве и отчаянии***.

В то же время оба варианта в принципе возможны.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта будут правильными.
Подробнее о повторении предлогов [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85/).